# XML to objects by unmarshalling using JAXB

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I want to convert XML to java by unmarshalling using JAXB.

And this is my employee.xml. I tried to convert but it shows the error javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deptname name="Research">
 <employee>
    <eid>r-001</eid>
    <ename>Dinesh R</ename>
    <age>35</age>
    <deptcode>d1</deptcode>
    <deptname>Research</deptname>
    <salary>20000</salary>
</employee>
</deptname>
<deptname name="Sales">
<employee>
    <eid>s-001</eid>
    <ename>Kanmani S</ename>
    <age>35</age>
    <deptcode>d2</deptcode>
    <deptname>Sales</deptname>
    <salary>30000</salary>
   </employee>
  </deptname>
<deptname name="Delivery">
  <employee>
    <eid>d-001</eid>
    <ename>Kanchana M</ename>
    <age>35</age>
    <deptcode>d3</deptcode>
    <deptname>Delivery</deptname>
    <salary>20000</salary>
</employee>
  </deptname>
```

Comment: Can you provide your employee and department classes? Also the full exception description

Comment: On first analysis, you have multiple documents at root. you should have only one document enclosing the rest. Like: `<departments> YOUR CURRENT XML<departments>`

Comment: This is my deptname.java  

        ' @XmlRootElement(name = "deptname")
          @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)       
         public class Deptname {
 @XmlAttribute(name = "Research")
 String research;
 
 @XmlAttribute(name = "Sales")
 String sales;
 @XmlAttribute(name = "Delivery")
 String delivery;
     //getter and setter

@XmlElement(name = "employee")
 List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
  
//getter and setter '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to XML [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/), you can only have one root element, so you should change your xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<departments>
    <deptname name="Research">
        <employee>
            <eid>r-001</eid>
            <ename>Dinesh R</ename>
            <age>35</age>
            <deptcode>d1</deptcode>
            <deptname>Research</deptname>
            <salary>20000</salary>
        </employee>
    </deptname>
    <deptname name="Sales">
        <employee>
            <eid>s-001</eid>
            <ename>Kanmani S</ename>
            <age>35</age>
            <deptcode>d2</deptcode>
            <deptname>Sales</deptname>
            <salary>30000</salary>
        </employee>
    </deptname>
    <deptname name="Delivery">
        <employee>
            <eid>d-001</eid>
            <ename>Kanchana M</ename>
            <age>35</age>
            <deptcode>d3</deptcode>
            <deptname>Delivery</deptname>
            <salary>20000</salary>
        </employee>
    </deptname>
</departments>
```

Then you would need a class Departments to read that piece:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="departments")
public class Departments {
  List<Department> deptname;

  // Getters and setters
}
```

A test case would be:

```
@Test
  public void testXML() {
    try {
      File file = new File("./src/main/resources/employee.xml");
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Departments.class);

      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      Departments departments = (Departments) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
      System.out.println(departments);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Second, you do not have "Research" or "Sales" or "Delivery" attributes, you have an attribute "name" that can take any string value, therefore you need to change implementation:

```
public class Department {
  @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @XmlElement(name = "employee")
  private List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();

  // Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I run the code and i have got the output but its shows the xml format not like a java object. How do i get the java object instead of getting xml format.?

Comment: What do you mean by getting xml format?

Comment: while do the unmarshall its shows the output in xml only not in java object.

Comment: Because i want to create a rest service for it. Once its converted to java object and i could be able to create service then mapping into the controller.

Comment: If you want to return object as JSON, you only need to configure your rest endpoint to handle it as JSON: `@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Comment: hello sir, still I didn't get output for the unmarshalling.. Its repeatedly showing the xml file not the java objects.

Comment: Would need you to update the questiin with the test of your Code otherwise it is difficult to understand